# Property 'message' does not exist on type 'HttpErrorResponse'

Tags: angular

I have imported HttpErrorResponse as :

```
import { HttpClient, HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
```

And have declared a function as :

```
 private handleError(err:HttpErrorResponse) {

    console.log(err.message);
    return Observable.throw(err.message);

}
```

But I'm Getting an error regarding the 'message' property...

> Property 'message' does not exist on type 'HttpErrorResponse'

Comment: What is the exact error?

Comment: Property 'message' does not exist on type 'HttpErrorResponse'

Comment: That's pretty odd. Which version of Angular are you using? Did you try looking at the source file of HttpErrorResponse to see how it looked? Should be [like this](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpErrorResponse).

Comment: Can you show the code where `handleError` is passed please?

Comment: @Jeto ..  Removed the 'readonly' from 'readonly message: string;' inside the source file of HttpErrorResponse ... And the error has been removed.. Did i do anything wrong??

Comment: Does it happen doing this: `return Observable.throw(new Error(err.message));` ?

Comment: It is rather `error.error.message` that you should use ? https://angular.io/guide/http#getting-error-details

Answer (score 0):

You set error type HttpErrorResponse -  private handleError(err:**HttpErrorResponse**). And that type really has no propetry "message".

Just use change to: private handleError(err), so no type will be setted by default.